# htb multiply root rate by 8

Tags: networking, traffic-shaping, tc, htb

I am changing the queue discipline to HTB, creating a parent node, and 3 children which are the classes.

```
sudo tc qdisc add dev em1 root handle 1: htb
sudo tc qdisc add dev em1 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 1000kbps ceil 1000kbps
sudo tc class add dev em1 parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate 400kbps ceil 1000kbps
sudo tc class add dev em1 parent 1:1 classid 1:20 htb rate 200kbps ceil 1000kbps
sudo tc class add dev em1 parent 1:1 classid 1:30 htb rate 400kbps ceil 1000kbps
```

However, when I use the `show` command, the factors of rate and ceil are multiplied by 8!

```
sudo tc class show dev em1
class htb 1:1 root rate 8Mbit ceil 8Mbit burst 1600b cburst 1600b
class htb 1:10 parent 1:1 prio 0 rate 3200Kbit ceil 8Mbit burst 1600b cburst 1600b
class htb 1:20 parent 1:1 prio 0 rate 1600Kbit ceil 8Mbit burst 1600b cburst 1600b
class htb 1:30 parent 1:1 prio 0 rate 3200Kbit ceil 8Mbit burst 1600b cburst 1600b
```

What could possibly cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tc, bps stands for Bytes per seconds.
You can use kbit instead.

Comment: Oh, did not notice! So simple. Many thanks!